# Fusing intermediate outputs of CNN and GRU models

Tags: conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, feature-extraction

In my research work, I have used a two stream model for activity recognition. First stream is based on CNN, while second stream is based on GRU. I have extracted features from the last fully connected layers of both the streams, and then train an SVM classifier for classification.

Is it also possible to combine output/feature maps from the intermediate layers of both the streams, and then train an SVM?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In semi-supervised classification, this method is preferred, where the features from last few layer are concatenated and a model(svm, logistic regression) is trained on top of that.

This method make sense, because, network has learned the useful features in the data. So it can be utilized to train another model.

Comment: Yes I agree with you that last few layers can give the best features for classification.

But is it possible to extract some kind of feature maps from intermediate layers of a GRU? I have done the same for a CNN, but I'm not sure about RNN like LSTM or GRU because an RNN returns state information (and not any feature maps).

So plz guide me in this regard.